# Flow confuses type of React component property callback

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

Somehow flow confuses the type of the `onValueChange`callback of a Picker component. This is my setup:

I defined the State type with `gender`as a string in it:

```js
type State = {
  gender: string,
  weight: number
// code omitted

};
```

which is initialised in the constructor (which is not mandatory isn't it?)

```js
export default class CustomComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { gender: '', weight: 0 };
  }

  render() {

    const { gender, weight } = this.state;

// code omitted
```

And in the Picker component I want to set the gender state in the `onValueChange`callback like so:

```
 <Picker
   style={styles.inputElement}
   selectedValue={gender}
   onValueChange={itemvalue => {
   this.setState({ gender: itemvalue, isDirty: true });
    }}
     > // code omitted
```

But there Flow shows an error at itemvalue: this.setState({ gender: **itemvalue**, isDirty: true })

```
Cannot call `this.setState` with object literal bound to `partialState` because  number [1] is incompatible with  string [2].Flow(InferError)
```

I also tried to typedefine itemvalue like so:

```
onValueChange={(itemvalue: string) => ....}
```

But this just moves the error at the newly added `string`

It looks like flow thinks itemvalue is a number but instead it is a string right?

Comment: The Picker component is telling flow to expect a number, you'll need to include the Picker component's implementation before we can help.

Comment: well that is the react native Picker. That is what I do not understand, why does it expect a number. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at [the definition of the `onValueChange` event on the react-native Picker component](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Picker/Picker.js#L73), the component in use here:

```
onValueChange?: ?(itemValue: string | number, itemIndex: number) => mixed,
```

So the type of the first argument of the callback is a union of `string` and `number`, `string | number`. Why is this? Well, if we look at implementation of `Picker` we'll see that it's built with the assumption that [the option values will either be numbers or strings](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Picker/Picker.js#L31-L35). This is more convenient than only allowing strings for example, because then you would need to convert strings to numbers in some cases. The downside here is that every user (who is using the flow types) is forced to handle both the string and number cases, even when they are clearly working in only one or the other type. This is the type of problem than can generally be solved using generics, but hasn't been here, so we are left with having to handle both cases.

So let's look at our handler:

```
itemvalue => {
   this.setState({ gender: itemvalue, isDirty: true });
}
```

First of all, let's type the argument correctly so that we are clear about what we're working with:

```
(itemvalue: string | number) => {
   this.setState({ gender: itemvalue, isDirty: true });
}
```

This still errors of course, because `gender` in the state is a `string`, but at least we can now very clearly see why this is happening.

In our implementation we *know* that `itemvalue` will always be a string, otherwise something has become horribly broken in some fundamental way. We're only providing string option values, so if we get a number back then something absolutely terrible has happened. This kind of concrete expectation is generally called an "invariant." In our case, it's an invariant that `itemvalue` is a `string`.

So what do we do about it? Usually when you have a union of multiple types and you want to deal with the various cases of the different types in the union, [you're going to use type refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-unions-refinements). So something like this:

```
(itemvalue: string | number) => {
  if (typeof itemvalue === 'string') {
    (itemvalue: string); // do something with the string case
  } else {
    (itemvalue: number); // do something with the number case
  }
}
```

So one possible solution would be to just ignore the number case, as it should never actually occur anyway:

```
(itemvalue: string | number) => {
  if (typeof itemvalue === 'string') {
    this.setState({ gender: itemvalue, isDirty: true });
  }
}
```

This should work fine, but it's a little weird that it's just ignoring the `number` case, that input came from somewhere and should probably be dealt with in some way. So what should happen when an invariant is violated? That is, what should our callback actually *do* if we receive a number (something that should be impossible)?

Generally, when an invariant is violated, the common behavior is to throw an exception, and exceptions can also be used for type refinement in flow:

```
(itemvalue: string | number) => {
  if (typeof itemvalue === 'number') throw new Error('itemvalue should be a string!');

  this.setState({ gender: itemvalue, isDirty: true });
}
```

But really we should solve this problem in the general case, surely we'll run into it in more than one place in a complex codebase. What if we pull it out into some kind of assertion function?

```
const assert = (check: boolean, message: string) => {
  if (!check) {
    throw new Error(message);
  }
};

(itemvalue: string | number) => {
  assert(typeof itemvalue === 'number', 'itemvalue should be a string!');

  this.setState({ gender: itemvalue, isDirty: true }); // error!
}
```

Now our error has returned, because type refinement in flow only survives block scope. Once our `assert` function returns, `itemvalue` goes back to being `string | number`. Luckily, flow has a built in special case for this type of function, but as a function named `invariant`. We can implement our own `invariant` function, but we should probably just use an npm package like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/invariant). This special case in flow exists because it is how invariants are handled within the react codebase and at facebook more generally. So, what does our handler look like with `invariant`?

```
import invariant from 'invariant';

// ...

(itemvalue: string | number) => {
  invariant(typeof itemvalue === 'number', 'itemvalue should be a string!');

  this.setState({ gender: itemvalue, isDirty: true });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the great explanation, unfortuntatly I can not check it because all of a sudden flow (or at least the flow language support plugin for vscode) stopped working without any error. So I will get back to your solution as soon as I fixed that...

Comment: Take your time!